# Using MOXY's JAXB Implementation using annotations based + on the fly mapping

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I'm writing a RESTful WS application using RESTEasy library.
I've been looking for a way to dynamically modify certain model/xml mapping and found the MOXY's JAXB implementation.

The problem is when I specify the MOXY's implementation using the file jaxb.properties, when I try to retrieve the JAXBContext, I get the following exception :

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: Name collision.  Two classes have the XML type with uri http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema and name anyType.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20130912-6b5e067): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
```

No such exception is raised using RESTEasy JAXB.
I tried to remove all @XMLElement to avoid references to some unknowns classes but nothing works.
Here is the class definition :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class User extends HistorizedObject implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @XmlElement(name="refNumber")
    private String m_ref;

    ...
}
```

And the way I try to retrieve the JAXBContext :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
```

There is no clue on which classes are collisionning.
Do you have an idea ?

Thx

**EDIT :**

Here is my jaxb.properties file located in the same package as the class User :

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Here is the HistorizedObject class definition located in a different package than the User class :

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public abstract class HistorizedObject implements PersistentObject, Cloneable{

        @XmlElement(name="userCreate")
        protected String userCreate="";

        @XmlElement(name="userUpdate")
        protected String userUpdate; 

        ...
}
```

My application is running under JBoss 4.2.3GA using RestEasy 2.3.5.
The moxy's build version I use is specified in the exception message above.
Let me know if you need more information.

**EDIT2 :**

Retrieving JAXBContext when I specify the class Login (located in the same package as User) is working fine.
Annotations on Login class are the same as those on User class, so obviously something in the source code of this class is raising the Exception.
The problem is that this class is 3000 lines long...
Do you have any idea where and what I should start looking for ?

Here is the class definition of the Login class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "login")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Login extends HistorizedObject implements java.io.Serializable
{

    /** Email address */
    @XmlElement(name="emailAddress")
    private String m_email;

    ...
}
```

**EDIT3 :**

Ok so I found something interesting.
Here is the code inside the User class leading to the name collision :

```
public static final HashMap<String, Object[]> USERTYPEOFELEM;
    static
    {
        USERTYPEOFELEM = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
        USERTYPEOFELEM.put("GENDER", new Object[]{Constants.IMPORT_LISTOFVALUE, "gender"});
        ...
    }
```

I understand Objects in this HashMap could be unresolved and collide but this hashmap is not annotated and should not be marshalled then right ?
Is that a bug from MOXY's implementation or did I miss something ?

Comment: Can you post additional information.  At this point I'm not sure how to go about recreating the issue you are seeing.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan posted additional information

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I may have found a bug in MOXY's JAXB implementation. Could you confirm please ?

Comment: There may be a bug here.  I'm still trying to recreate the use case based on the information you have provided. Could you open a bug and attach a test case to it:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink.  Or could you start an email conversation with me through my blog:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**Solution**

Based on the results of an offline conversation the solution to the issue was to use the following EclipseLink bundle:

- org.eclipse.persistence.asm

In combination with the EclipseLink bundles that were already being used:

- org.eclipse.persistence.core
- org.eclipse.persistence.moxy

**Reason**

MOXy byte code generates some objects (leveraging ASM) when creating mappings for `Map` objects.  Without these generated classes MOXy's metadata generation was failing.